# How to execute org-mode source block asynchronously in session?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have an org file with notes about how to setup my project. One of the notes has some shell scripts, like this:

```
#+begin_src sh :dir ~/Workspace/MyProject :session cmake-setup
cmake -B build-debug -S . -G Ninja \
  -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
#+end_src
```

I can hit `C-c C-c` there and execute the shell command. But the problem is that Emacs hangs for 5-10 seconds while that command runs. When it's done I can switch to the `cmake-setup` buffer and see the output. But I'd like to switch to the shell buffer right away and see the progress. This will be essential when commands take more than a few seconds.

I found `ob-async` and added the `:async` header to the source block. It stops freezing emacs, but it ignores the `:session` header and puts the huge amount of output into my org file.

Is there a way to make my code block execute asynchronously and keep it running in the session?

Comment: Not sure, but doesn't the ampersand at the end of your shell command help?

Comment: You can set the `:results silent` for the block if you don't want to see a huge output.

Comment: Oh my, I'm an idiot. Haha. Yes, the `&` did it. Thank you.